# Passing parameter to the homepage using Yii2

Tags: php, web, yii2

I created a `RegisterController` and after a successful registration I would like to forward the user back to the homepage, problem is, how can I pass a parameter to the [homepage](http://localhost) without using the redirect call to the [controller](http://localhost/MainController/index) because they display the long urls. I am passing parameter to the homepage so it could display that the user successfully registered on the site.

Tips please? Thanks.

Comment: Try `return $this->redirect('/');`

Comment: what do you mean by long urls

Comment: @KiranMuralee when I use `$this->redirect(\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl("main/index"));` in the method it will be redirected to a long url which is `127.0.0.1/main/index`. But I only want to use `$this->goHome()` so it will be redirected to the same homepage but it's url is shorter `127.0.0.1` but at the same time i want to pass a parameter to the controller's index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass array with redirect method like  :

```
  $data = array('data1'=>'data1', 'data2'=>'data2');    
  return $this->redirect(['site/dashboard', 'data' => $data]);
```

It could be very simple as you are thinking like redirection would be so long url and all.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it says `PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Array to string conversion`

Comment: can you try now please?

Comment: uhm I already don't have the sitecontroller, I am using maincontroller
`return $this->redirect(['main/index', 'id' => 1]);`
I already tried this, but the url on the website shows something like `localhost/main/index?id=1` I am actually looking for something like `localhost` alone without the `id` displayed on the url

Comment: Okay I found a solution about the long url though I still need help though. I added in the prettyUrl: `'rules' => ['/' => 'main/redirect']` but the result url is `localhost/?id=1` what is the proper rule declaration to come up with just `localhost` in the url?

Answer (score 0):

[yii\base\View](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html) has special [$params](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$params-detail) property.

You can set it like this before rendering:

```
use Yii;

Yii::$app->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
```

Inside a controller you can set it like this:

```
$this->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
```

Then it will be available in views (including main layout):

```
/* @var $this yii\web\View */

echo $this->params['customParam'];
```

Comment: isn't this a bad design since this is like a global variable?

Comment: best way is to use redirect, and pass data